# How can I tell if a ttyUSBX is connected?

Tags: linux, tty

I wish to determine if USB connected board has been power cycled. The usb might be either ttyUSB1 or ttyUSB2

I attempted to manually verify that the USB is connected, which works fine, but now I am trying to script the process. I wish to pause the script until these files disappear and then resume when it reappears.

I tried using the `[[ -f /dev/ttyUSB3 ]]` check, however it appears to always return the same value, even if `ls /dev/ttyUSB*` doesnt return that file (file handle? idk).

```
1 #!/usr/bin/env bash
5 if [ ! -f ./file.hex]; then
6     echo "build failed chump"
7     exit 1
8 fi
9 ./loader -l `ls /dev/ttyUSB{1,2} 2>/dev/null` -s reload.sc
10 echo "Time to Power Cycle Mike..........."
11 while [ -f /dev/ttyUSB{1,2} ]
12     do
13         sleep 1
14     done
15 while [ ! -f /dev/ttyUSB{1,2} ]
16     do
17         sleep 1
18     done
19 
20 ./loader -l `ls /dev/ttyUSB{1,2} 2>/dev/null`
```

In the second code example the first line of code did not return /dev/ttyUSB3.

Comment: You can't simple write a `udev` event?

Comment: And those aren't files, they're character devices.  The bash test operator for those if `[[ -c /dev/ttyUSB ]]` ...